# How to image write in pdf through html in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

How to image write in pdf through html in Swift 4?

```
func createPDF(html: String, formmatter: UIViewPrintFormatter, filename: String) -> String
{
    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: sampleHTML)

    // 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer

    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)
    render.drawPrintFormatter(formmatter, forPageAt: 0)

    // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect

    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize.zero)
    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // 5. Save PDF file

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
     print(documentsPath)

    if pdfData.write(toFile: "\(documentsPath)/file.pdf", atomically: true)
    {
        pdfFilePath = "\(documentsPath)/file.pdf"
        var URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pdfFilePath!)
        storedPdfFileData = try! Data(contentsOf:URL as URL)
        fileName = URL.lastPathComponent
        print("FileName\(fileName!)")
        self.UserDefaultForfileName.setValue(self.fileName, forKey: "FILE")
    }
    else
    {
        print("choose how to handle error here")

    }
    return pdfFilePath!
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Your question should include all relevant details (i.e. expected behavior/input/output, any occuring errors or problems) and should be formatted correctly. Right now, it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Is this just you posting how to do it or do you have an issue with your code?

Comment: i have an issue

Comment: what are you looking for? do you want to add image as pdf?

Comment: yes  i want to add images

Answer (score 0):

If we have correctly understood, we can see two different requirements from your comments

1) you want to save the html pages to pdf.

or

2) you want to create pdf from images (list of UIImage).

for 1st approach:-

You should be using WKWebView to show html pages in your viewController. ( To know how to use WKWebView, you may search help from Stackoverflow. ) In the viewControler, you can have Button click event for 'printWebPagetoPDF" function. The function is as under.

```
func printWebPagetoPDF( theHeight:CGFloat = 0 ) {
    var isHeightFound = true
    let deviceW = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let deviceH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let width = min(deviceW, deviceH)
    var height = theHeight
    if height <= 0 {
        height = max(deviceW, deviceH)
        isHeightFound = false
    }

    let fileParentPath = "<absolute path to save pdf file>" + "/"

    let inDateTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inDateTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmm"

    let dateTimeFileString = "test\(inDateTimeFormatter.string(from: Date()))"
    let pdfFileName =  dateTimeFileString + ".pdf"
    let sharePdfFilePath = fileParentPath + pdfFileName

    // - 1 - Grab the webView's print context
    let fmt = myWKWebView.viewPrintFormatter()

    fmt.perPageContentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10) //Page margins

    // - 2 - Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer
    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)

    // - 3 - Assign paperRect and printableRect
    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)    //width: 841.85, height: 595.22) //Page size
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // - 4 - Create PDF context and draw
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, page, nil)
    print( render.numberOfPages )
    render.prepare(forDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, render.numberOfPages-1))
    for i in 0..<render.numberOfPages {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        render.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    // - 5 - Save the PDF file
    let path = sharePdfFilePath
    pdfData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)

}
```

for 2nd approach:-

You may try following code to create pdf from images. I have not tested it properly, but you can try yourselves. mySelectedArray is the sequence of indexes of images to add in pdf. dataArray is array of UIImages. "import PDFKit" is required on start of swift file.

```
 // The url to save the data to
 let pdfFileName = "<some path>" + "/" + "test.pdf"
 let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pdfFileName)

 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
       // Create an empty PDF document
       let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()
       pdfDocument.delegate = self

       for index in mySelectedArray {
            // Load or create your UIImage
            let image = dataArray[index].image

            // Create a PDF page instance from your image
            let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: image)

            // Insert the PDF page into your document
            pdfDocument.insert(pdfPage!, at: 0)
       }
       // Get the raw data of your PDF document
       let data = pdfDocument.dataRepresentation()

       // Save the data to the url
       try! data!.write(to: url)
 }
```

If possible, please comment clearly, for any further assistance.